# conditional stored procedure performance vs. code build statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, case

currenty i am working on a report system for our data archive.
the aim is to select data for every 1st of  a month, every full hour and so on.
So I have a bunch of parameters to select the data down to a single hour.

To achieve that I used CASE statements to adjust the select like this:

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(cd.Timestamp) as Mintime,
    --Hours
    CASE
        WHEN
            @SelHour IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            DATEPART(HOUR, cd.Timestamp)
    END as Hour,
    ... -- more CASES up to DATEPART(YEAR, cd.Timestamp)
    FROM dbo.CustomerData cd
    ... -- filter data and other stuff
```

This statements works good for me so far, but I am a bit worried about the performance of the stored procedure. Because I don't know how the server will behave with this "changing" statement. The result can vary between a 20 row result up to a 250.000 rows and more. Depending on the given parameters. As far as I know the sql server saves the query plan and reuses it for future execution.
When it saves the plan for the 20 row result the performance for the 250.000 result is propably pretty poor.

Now I am wondering whats the better aproach. Using this stored procedure or create the statement inside my c# backend and pass the "adjusted" statement to the sql server?

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 20 rows result set it will work good anywhere. But for returning 250k records to c# code seems change in design for this code since loading 250k records in memory & looping will also consume significant memory and such concurrent requests from different session/user will multiply load exponentially.

Anyway to address problem with SQL Server reusing same query plan, you can recompile query plans selectively or every time. These are options available for Recompile execution plan:

1. **OPTION(RECOMPILE)**

   `SELECT
       MIN(cd.Timestamp) as Mintime,
       --Hours
       CASE
           WHEN
               @SelHour IS NOT NULL
           THEN
               DATEPART(HOUR, cd.Timestamp)
       END as Hour,
       ... -- more CASES up to DATEPART(YEAR, cd.Timestamp)
       FROM dbo.CustomerData cd
       ... -- filter data and other stuff
   OPTION(RECOMPILE)`
2. **WITH RECOMPILE Option** this will recompile execution plan every time

   `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspStoredPrcName 
      @ParamName varchar(30) = 'abc'

   WITH RECOMPILE

   AS

       ...`
3. **RECOMPILE Query Hint** providing `WITH RECOMPILE` in execute

**NOTE:** this will require CREATE PROCEDURE permission in the database and ALTER permission on the schema in which the procedure is being created.

`EXECUTE uspStoredPrcName  WITH RECOMPILE;

GO`

4. **sp_recompile** System Stored Procedure

**NOTE:** Requires ALTER permission on the specified procedure.

`EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.uspStoredPrcName ';

GO`

For more details on Recompile refer Microsoft Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: None of those RECOMPILE methods work as well as statement level `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. This is the only way of getting the Parameter Embedding Optimization and a truly suitable execution plan for the runtime parameter values

Comment: Agreed @MartinSmith, Adding to answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The reports will be added to a queue before execution and limit the number of concurent operations. 
I didn't know the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, looks quite promessing I give it a try. 
For `WITH RECOMPILE` I always thought its bad practice to use it in a statement by default.